# remove the intersection in 2 arrays in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have 2 object lists with 2 fields:

```
let users1 = [{ name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid3'},
              { name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid1'},
              { name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid2'}];

let users2 = [{ name: 'joe',  uuid:'uuid5'},
              { name: 'joe',  uuid: 'uuid1'}, 
              { name: 'joe',  uuid: 'uuid2'}];
```

I want to delete the objects inside each list with the intersection over the uuid.

```
let users1 = [{ name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid3'}]; // object with uuid1 and uuid2 deleted
let users2 = [{ name: 'joe',  uuid:'uuid5'}];     // object with uuid1 and uuid2 deleted
```

in the code below I am extracting the uuids from the obj lists and put them into a new array each

```
let a =[];  
let b = [];
a = users1.map(s => s.uuid); // uuids from list 1 ['uuid3', 'uuid1', 'uuid2']
b = users2.map(s => s.uuid); // uuids from list 2 ['uuid5', 'uuid1', 'uuid2']
```

then use lodash to get the intersection:

```
let e = [];
e = _.intersection(a,b); // intersection = [uuid1, uuid2]
```

we can use the list e to do the remove on users1 and users2

but then I am not really sure on how to do the delete

any idea, suggestion or example would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the intersection is actually finding the difference - use [`_.differenceBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceBy) to filter each user by finding the items with a `uuid` that doesn't exist on the other user:

```js
const users1 = [{ name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid3'},
              { name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid1'},
              { name: 'barney',  uuid: 'uuid2'}];

const users2 = [{ name: 'joe',  uuid:'uuid5'},
              { name: 'joe',  uuid: 'uuid1'}, 
              { name: 'joe',  uuid: 'uuid2'}];
              
const user1n = _.differenceBy(users1, users2, 'uuid');
const user2n = _.differenceBy(users2, users1, 'uuid');

console.log(user1n);
console.log(user2n);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```